# IntelliJ / Niagara Module Plugin

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, maven-repository, niagara-4

I'm receiving the following error while attempting to sync gradle in JetBrains IntelliJ while trying to work on a [Tridium](https://www.tridium.com/us/en) [Niagara](https://www.tridium.com/us/en/Products/niagara) project.

### Error

```
Build file '<<project_path>>\build.gradle' line: 1

A problem occurred evaluating project ':dcEclypse-rt'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
   > Could not find com.tridium:niagara-module-plugin:3.0.18.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Niagara/EC-Net4-4.11.0.142/bin/ext/niagara-module-plugin-3.0.18.jar
       - file:/C:/Niagara/EC-Net4-4.11.0.142/bin/ext/niagara-module-plugin.jar
       - file:/C:/Niagara/EC-Net4-4.11.0.142/bin/ext/bcfips/niagara-module-plugin-3.0.18.jar
       - file:/C:/Niagara/EC-Net4-4.11.0.142/bin/ext/bcfips/niagara-module-plugin.jar
       - file:/C:/Niagara/EC-Net4-4.11.0.142/etc/m2/repository/com/tridium/niagara-module-plugin/3.0.18/niagara-module-plugin-3.0.18.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/tridium/niagara-module-plugin/3.0.18/niagara-module-plugin-3.0.18.pom
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 5s
```

### What I've Tried

My solution references `{NIAGARA_HOME}/niagara.gradle` which references a local maven repository:

```
maven { url "${rootProject.ext.niagara_home}/etc/m2/repository" }
```

I've confirmed that the jar in question is at:

```
etc\m2\repository\com\tridium\niagara-module-plugin\3.0.18\niagara-module-plugin-3.0.18.jar
```

Unfortunately, its .pom file is being sought instead. Do I have to do something to index this repository?

### IntelliJ Version

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-232.8660.185, built on July 26, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.7+7-b1000.6 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 20
Registry:
    ide.experimental.ui=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    uk.co.hadoopathome.intellij.avro.intellijavroviewer (3.1.0)
    Lombook Plugin (232.8660.199)
    com.microsoft.tooling.msservices.intellij.azure (3.79.1-2023.2)

Kotlin: 232-1.9.0-IJ8660.185
```

Comment: Have you considered adding the JAR directly
implementation name: 'niagara-module-plugin-3.0.18'
or by the filename:
implementation files('etc\m2\repository\com\tridium\niagara-module-plugin\3.0.18\niagara-module-plugin-3.0.18.jar')
It also might be worth trying adding mavenLocal() repository explicitly to your Gradle Project.